# I2P and remote node access

Tags: kovri, i2p, remote-access

Will the planned I2P implementation make impossible to use a remote node?

(To use a remote node, you need the set an IP address in your lite client)

Comment: We're waiting on an answer to this question here: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/is-it-possible-to-use-light-wallets-remote-nodes-with-kovri