# Can remote nodes still be used with kovri?

Tags: full-node, kovri, remote-access

If kovri is mandatory for all nodes, could remote nodes still be used for my local wallet?

Comment: We're awaiting an answer to this question here: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/is-it-possible-to-use-light-wallets-remote-nodes-with-kovri